# One generic custom exception or many in Service Layer (Spring)

Tags: java, spring, exception, service-layer

I am creating my very first Spring project (plus Hibernate). So far, I've only created two Entities: User and Group. For those entities there are their DAOs. And now I am in the Service layer.

Defining the UserService interface I started to wonder what's better: 1. Create a generic custom exception with an error code (like web error codes: 404, 500...) or, 2. Create many specific custom exceptions such as: UserNotExistException, GroupNotExist, UserNotActive, GroupNotActive...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that is better to have one exception per meaning of the exception, not per object: NotExistsException, NotActive,... where you can pass specific messages (or even the objects) to show more information about the object which caused the exception. Why? Because if the application start growing:

- You will need to create a lot of new exception classes, what means a lot of extra work.
- If the meaning of the exception itself doesn´t change because of the object (for example, in NotExistsException) you are duplicating code.
- If you want to change something to a type of exception (for example, add a new constructor, modify a message, etc), if you have multiple classes, you will need to modify all these files.

Answer (score 2):

It is good to use a generic custom exception with different error code along with error trace.